# How to solve a 1D spring system?

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I have a problem which reduces to a simplified 1D spring-mass system, in which I do not care about spring constants nor masses (they can assumed to be the same everywhere). I'm pretty sure it boils to solving a system of linear equations, but I can't quite figure out how to formulate it. Pardon the lack of formalism of the description below:

Given a series of `n` nodes along a 1D axis and `m` springs connecting any two nodes (adjacent or not) with rest lengths r<sub>1</sub> to r<sub>m</sub> and spring constant `k` (can be assumed to be 1 for simplicity). Solve for the distances d<sub>1</sub> to d<sub>n-1</sub> between every adjacent node when the spring system comes to rest.

I used a physics engine to simulate an example with 4 nodes and the following springs, where the notation `x-y:r` means a spring connecting nodes `x` and `y` with rest length `r`: `1-2:100, 2-3:100, 3-4:100, 1-2:100, 2-4:167, 1-3:167, 3-4:100`. The result is as illustrated below, where the two central nodes have been pulled slightly closer together due to the action of the longer springs:

[image: Sample spring system at rest]

How do I go about solving a system like this? If it is possible to do so with a series of linear equations, what would they look like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Example**

```
A              B              C
|---k11, r11---|---k12, r12---|
|---k21, r21---|---k22, r22---|
```

**Model**

- Total force on A is 0. Same for B. Same for C.
- Model force from each spring by Hooke's law.
- Assume no friction on A, B, and C.
- Assume the boards can only move left or right.

Let distance between A and B be $d_1$

Let distance between B and C be $d_2$

$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
0 &= F_{11} + F_{21} \\
0 &= -F_{11} - F_{21} + F_{12} + F_{22} \\
0 &= -F_{12} - F_{22} \\
F_{11} &= -k_{11}(r_{11} - d_{1}) \\
F_{21} &= -k_{21}(r_{21} - d_{1}) \\
F_{12} &= -k_{12}(r_{12} - d_{2}) \\
F_{22} &= -k_{22}(r_{22} - d_{2}) \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$

Simplify:

$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
k_{11}d_{1} +  k_{21}d_{1} &= k_{11}r_{11} + k_{21}r_{21} \\
k_{12}d_{2} +  k_{22}d_{2} &= k_{12}r_{12} + k_{22}r_{22} \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$

Matrix form:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11} + k_{21} & 0 \\
0 & k_{12} + k_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d_{1} \\
d_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11}r_{11} + k_{21}r_{21} \\
k_{12}r_{12} + k_{22}r_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

**Solution**

$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
d_{1} &= \frac{k_{11}r_{11} + k_{21}r_{21}}{k_{11} + k_{21}} \\
d_{2} &= \frac{k_{12}r_{12} + k_{22}r_{22}}{k_{12} + k_{22}} \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Aaah, I had thought of doing that only for the middle rods. Looks sensible! https://tinyurl.com/ybszvbj5